# Purpose of keys above each Braille key on Braille display

Tags: accessibility, hardware

What are the keys on a Humanware Braillant keyboard, the ones found above each Braille key, the ones that look like small knobs that can be made to slide downwards towards the keys and probably slide back upwards on their own when released?

What do these do? Do these slide the positions of the keys on the display by making them sink downwards and then slide back up?

[image: Humanware Braillant keyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those are cursor router keys.**

By pressing a router key, you move the mouse cursor to that location in the line of text, which then allows you to edit at that specific location.

[HumanWare Demonstration](https://youtu.be/9yLZRPXJ8lo?t=3m42s)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question. If the cursor router key positions the key before the character marked by the corresponding Braille key, then how do you place the cursor beyond the last character appearing on the Braille display. What key would you press to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington In the image you provided, there are four wide buttons on the bottom face of the keyboard (below the two spacebar buttons). By pressing these buttons, you can display the next section of braille text before or after the current section you are on, in the current line of text you are on. So if you wanted to place the cursor router after the last braille cell on the display, you would advance the line section and press the first (left-most) cursor router key.

Comment: @JackMaddington If you think my answer properly answered the question, please mark it as the chosen answer. Thank you.